# No qualifying bean of type [service.NewsServiceImpl] is defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an error in Spring MVC.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [service.NewsServiceImpl] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1088)
at controller.Testing.main(Testing.java:24)
```

NewsDAImpl Code is :

```
@Repository 
public class NewsDAImpl implements NewsDA {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager context;  

@Override
public News ... Some Other Codes
```

My NewsServiceImpl class :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class NewsServiceImpl implements NewsService{

@Autowired
private NewsDAImpl newsDa;

@Override
public News ... Some Other Codes
```

I write controller that has static void main, just for testing.
in that i wrote this :

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ProjectConfig.class);
```

then i just get news service with getBean method :

```
NewsServiceImpl service = context.getBean(NewsServiceImpl.class);
```

Comment: How is your `ProjectConfig`?

Comment: Never code to an implementation - code to an interface, so dont use DI on impl rather use interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
NewsServiceImpl service = context.getBean(NewsServiceImpl.class);
```

to

```
NewsService service = context.getBean(NewsService.class);
```

You have `NewServiceImpl` annotated with `@Transactional`, so by default spring will create a proxy which of course implements `NewsService` instead of `NewsServiceImpl`.